# Use NS[UI]ScrollView to manipulate projection

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, uikit

I have a simple metal setup which draw image in the middle of `MTKView`. I wish I could add pinch zoom and other functionality as we have in scroll views, so i can zoom image and move it around with some thresholds.

I also don't want to implement it myself since my app will live in both Mac OS and iOS and this is twice more code to support and write.

Is there a way I could use default scroll view controlls to manipulate my projection? I mean set scroll view somehow on top of my view and get some data in delegate manner or whatever.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try `Metal2DScrollable` sample code.   The idea is that:

1. place MTKView behind (not a subview) UIScrollView,
2. Place dummy content view as a subview of UIScrollView
3. Make the dummy content view to be the target of zooming
4. Set up UIScrollView properly such as contentSize, contentInset etc.
5. Make both UIScrollView and dummy content view to be transparent
6. Calculate transform from dummy content view's bounds -> MTKView's coordinate -> device coordinate
7. Apply that transform when rendering with Metal

So, MTKView is not in the UIScrollView, but this tricks fools user's eyes.

https://github.com/codelynx/Metal2DScrollable

The same technique may work with macOS with some tweaks, but I haven't tried.

Comment: That is not exactly a solution, but I think the answer for the question is that "it is impossible" that is why I accepted the question

Comment: Note that one thing this doesn't account for is that if your scroll view has minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale, then the bouncing animation that scrolls the view back to the min/max scale won't be animated in the metal view because it's a CAAnimation. The only option to get around this that I've found is to disable bouncesZoom